how to hide navigation Title in swift

i make navigation title with seperated view
navigationItem.titleView = titleView 

so when i drag down
navigation title is out of the white background
i want clear background of navigation title
(when i drag down)
navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .clear

i clear background color so, it will not see
but it is not working
so i did no largetitlemode
and preferLargeTitles false
navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false

so i dont want to see the of navigation title (changed white) when i drag down
how to solve it?
or do i hide navigation title
and make another view and put in to main view ?
this is my HomeViewController.swift
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK: UI Components
    private let timelineTable: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView.backgroundColor = .orange
        return tableView
    }()
    
    // MARK: Life Cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(timelineTable)
        setupNavigationBar()
        timelineTableDelegate()
    

        configureConstraints()
        
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
        UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
    }
    
    
    
    // MARK: Functions
    private func setupNavigationBar() {
        let titleView = NavigationTitleView(with: "어디갈래?", subTitle: "우리 마을 구석구석")
        navigationItem.titleView = titleView
    
        // 알림 버튼 추가
        let bellButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "bell"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didTapAlarm))
        bellButton.tintColor = .label
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = bellButton
    }
    
    
    private func configureConstraints() {
        
        let timelineTableConstraints = [
            timelineTable.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 120),
            timelineTable.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            timelineTable.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            timelineTable.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ]
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(timelineTableConstraints)
    }
    
    
    private func timelineTableDelegate() {
        timelineTable.delegate = self
        timelineTable.dataSource = self
    }
    @objc private func didTapAlarm() {
        // 알림 버튼 탭 시 동작
    }

}


extension HomeViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Test"
        return cell
    }
}

this is my customTabBar.swift

import UIKit

class CustomTabBar: UIView {
    
    // MARK: UI Components
    
    // 버튼을 담을 스택뷰 생성
    private let stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .horizontal
        stack.distribution = .equalSpacing
        stack.alignment = .center
        stack.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        stack.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        stack.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        stack.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 20, bottom: 10, right: 20)
        return stack
    }()
    
    
    // 스택뷰에 들어갈 버튼 생성
    private let homeButton = createButton(systemName: "house.fill")
    private let searchButton = createButton(systemName: "magnifyingglass.circle.fill")
    private let addButton = createButton(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
    private let savedButton = createButton(systemName: "bookmark.fill")
    private let profileButton = createButton(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
    
    // 버튼이 눌렸을 때, 이를 확인하기 위한 변수 생성
    private var selectedButton: UIButton?
    
    
    // 데이터 전달을 위한 클로저 생성
    var onButtonTapped: ((Int) -> Void)?
    
    
    // MARK: Life Cycle
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
        // Set initial selected button
        buttonTapped(homeButton)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    
    
    private func setupView() {
        addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(homeButton)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(searchButton)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(addButton)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(savedButton)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(profileButton)
        
        homeButton.tag = 0
        searchButton.tag = 1
        addButton.tag = 2
        savedButton.tag = 3
        profileButton.tag = 4
        
        [homeButton, searchButton, addButton, savedButton, profileButton].forEach { button in
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
        
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    @objc private func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // Deselect the previous selected button
        if let selectedButton = selectedButton {
            selectedButton.tintColor = .label
        }
        
        // Select the new button
        sender.tintColor = .systemTeal

        selectedButton = sender
        
        // Trigger the callback
        onButtonTapped?(sender.tag)
    }
    
    
    // 버튼을 생성하는 함수
    private static func createButton(systemName: String) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: systemName), for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = .label

        return button
    }
}

